# Comparar dos valores de una propiedad de diferentes json

Tags: javascript, html, bucle-for, fetch

Necesito comparar de 2 json diferentes el valor de una propiedad para poder mostrar algo en pantalla. Por ejemplo :
1er json :

```
{
registros: [
        {
            "paciente": 2,
            "problema": {
             "nota": "Mano derecha amputada. Antibioticos"
        },
{
            "paciente": 3,
            "problema": {
            "nota": "Ecografia de 6ta semana."
            }
        },
]}
```

2do json:

```
{
pacientes: [
{
            "nroPaciente":  2,
            "nombre": "Anakin Skywalker",
            "edad": 50,
            "internado": true
        },
{
            "nroPaciente":  1,
            "nombre": "Emanuel Fernandez",
            "edad": 16,
            "internado": false
        }

]}
```

necesito comparar la propiedad ***nroPaciente*** con la otra ***paciente*** y si son iguales mostrar la propiedad ***nota***.
 Solo debo usar javascript, aclaro que los json los obtengo mediante un fetch y estoy mostrando otras propiedades con un for, etc.
Gracias :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var registros= {
registros: [
    {
        "paciente": 2,
        "problema": {
         "nota": "Mano derecha amputada. Antibioticos"
    }
 },
{
    "paciente": 3,
        "problema": {
        "nota": "Ecografia de 6ta semana."
        }
    },
]};
var pacientes= {
pacientes: [
{
        "nroPaciente":  2,
        "nombre": "Anakin Skywalker",
        "edad": 50,
        "internado": true
    },
{
        "nroPaciente":  1,
        "nombre": "Emanuel Fernandez",
        "edad": 16,
        "internado": false
    }

]};

function get_nota( pacienteid){
   let filtered=   registros.registros.filter(elemento=>elemento.paciente==pacienteid);
  return filtered[0];
}
//Recorrer pacientes, acceder a la propiedad pacientes que contiene
//la lista de los mismos
pacientes.pacientes.forEach( function(elemento){
    let pacienteCod= elemento.nroPaciente;
    console.log( get_nota( pacienteCod));

} 
);
```

Por cierto Te faltó una llave para cerrar el primer registro de paciente

Comment: quiero mostrar la cantidad de pacientes internados dependiendo, que se sumen los true y eso me de la cantidad de internados.. tengo un boton y ese dispara el evento; estoy intentando con un for pacientes y de ahi comparar medianrte un if si es true pero me devuelve un NaN